# Organizing React app in component/container

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am working with React Redux Starter Kit and am trying to organize my code in component/container and struggling a bit with finding the right process. I realize it's a bit if a loose line but Id like some input on how to better organize things.

Currently I have 3 files - CheckoutForm (a redux form), CheckoutView (a simple page that has the form), and CheckoutContainer which right now does nearly nothing. Following the advice from reading about component/container separation it seems that the CheckoutView should be the same but that I should perhaps pull the submit function out of it and put that in the CheckoutContainer?  How would I best rewire this code:

*CheckoutContainer.js*

```
import Checkout from '../components/CheckoutView'

export default Checkout
```

*CheckoutView.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from './CheckoutView.scss'
import CheckoutForm from '../forms/CheckoutForm'

const submit = require('../modules/submit').default

export const CheckoutView = () => (
  <div>
    <h4 className={classes.header}>Checkout</h4>
    <CheckoutForm onSubmit={submit}/>
  </div>
)

export default CheckoutView
```

*CheckoutForm.js*

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)

const CheckoutForm = (props) => {
  const { error, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="username" type="text" component={renderField} label="Username"/>
      <Field name="password" type="password" component={renderField} label="Password"/>
      {error && <strong>{error}</strong>}
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Log In</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'checkoutForm' 
})(CheckoutForm)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main purpose of the container is to digest the information the component needs to know from the store and pass it to it, and also to provide callbacks as props that will handle the dispatching of actions in the container, so the component only has to pass the parameters it knows, and that's it. This way your component knows and does exactly what it needs, and nothing else, and it's not even aware of Redux at all.

Looking at your code, you got it right

> I should perhaps pull the submit function out of it and put that in the CheckoutContainer

That's exactly what you should do, as it is the only thing the component does it should not care about.

In your container

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Checkout from '../components/CheckoutView';

const submit = require('../modules/submit').default

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return { onSubmit: submit };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Checkout);
```

And in the View:

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from './CheckoutView.scss'
import CheckoutForm from '../forms/CheckoutForm'

export const CheckoutView = ({ onSubmit }) => (
  <div>
    <h4 className={classes.header}>Checkout</h4>
    <CheckoutForm onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
  </div>
)

export default CheckoutView
```

As your application scales, you'll be ready to pass any information from the state to the component in `mapStateToProps` and additional callbacks in `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: Thank you. So I had pulled out the Redux line in the container. But is that the recommended way to pass props even if I have no need of redux for other things in that route?

Comment: If you did things by the book, that `../modules/submit` function should be an action. It is the recommended way, yes, but how much you're willing to integrate Redux into your development is your decision.

Comment: Why would I get an error: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React" in CheckoutView line 5?

Comment: I guess I need to import React in the form even though its not explicitly used. Weird.

Comment: It is explicitly used in the transpiled code, anywhere you use JSX syntax React must be defined.